# Provide data to Custom Error component angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using angular 13 and I have a custom error component, I am handling the httpresponse error in my interceptor like if any error happens I will invoke the error component with :

```
        error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.status === <whichever> && err.statusText === '<text>') {
            this.router.navigate(['error']);
```

In my router I have defined the route as below:

```
{
    path: 'error',
    component: ErrorComponent,
  }
```

In the **ErrorComponent** I have a variable *msg*, and in the template I am showing it like this:

```
<div *ngIf="msg">
        <div class="error">{{ msg }}</div>
 </div>
```

How can I pass data to this component from the interceptor? I would like to pass the err.message from httperror response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to communicate from an Interceptor to your routed component, I would use a service with a subject.

Here is a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-intermediary?file=src/app/app.component.ts). This demo showcases [component communication](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-component-communication-81e5e02c6cbe) with an intermediary service, but you would use that service in the exact same way to communicate between your interceptor and your component.